# Javascript function executed before previous function is done

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that contains a couple of tables.

At the beginning it checks the language and sets the corresponding translations.

At the end of the html file (after all the elements are loaded) the translations are set using javascript.

After that variables are requested via wifi.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxQHv.png) is what I see when I load the page.
The elements that don't need translation are shown before `set_language_for_raw_data_()` is executed.

I have checked Chrome's developer tools and saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ugqy.png).
It shows that `set_language_for_raw_data_()` is executed before `Raw_Data_Requests()`, but it does not show until `Raw_Data_Requests()` is done.

Is there a way to show the translations before `Raw_Data_Requests()` is executed?

Raw_data.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>    
  <script>
    checkLanguage(); //load language setting or use system default
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="site_unresponsive">
    <div id="inhalt">
      <h2 class="middle white_font expander" onclick="expander('raw_data')" id="raw_data_title"></h2>
      <ul class="hidden" id="raw_data">
          <table cellspacing="0" id="actual_meas">
            <tr>
              <td id="loading" style="display:none">Error: Connection lost</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td></td>
              <td id="Meas(0)">..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td id="Meas(1)">..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td>Ubat</td>
              <td id="Meas(2)">..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ibat</td>
              <td id="Meas(5)">..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td>U PWM</td>
              <td id="Meas(9)">..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="color:darkorange">LED</td>
              <td id="Meas(11)">&bull;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td style="color:green">LED</td>
              <td id="Meas(12)">&bull;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td id="Meas(19)">..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td></td>
              <td id="Meas(20)">..</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td id="Meas(100)">..</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </ul>
      <h2 class="middle white_font expander" onclick="expander('version')" id="version_title"></h2>
      <div class="hidden" id="version">
        <table cellspacing="0" class="data_tab" id="version_details">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td id="device_version">~DeviceVersion~</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <h2 class="middle white_font expander" onclick="expander('cumulatives')" id="cumulatives_title"></h2>
      <ul class="hidden" id="cumulatives">
        <li class="w300">
          <table cellspacing="0" id="cuml">
            <tr class="odd">
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(0)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(1)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(2)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(3)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(4)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(5)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(6)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(7)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
              <td></td>
              <td>~Cumulatives(8)~</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td style="white-space:nowrap;">~Cumulatives(14)~</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h2 class="middle white_font expander" onclick="expander('error')" id="error_title"></h2>
      <div class="hidden" id="error" style="overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
        <table cellspacing="0" class="data_tab" id="error_history">
          <tr>
            <th>Nr</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>U</th>
            <th>I</th>
            <th>PWM</th>
            <th>T</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(0,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(0,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(0,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(0,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(0,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(0,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(0,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(1,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(1,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(1,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(1,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(1,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(1,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(1,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(2,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(2,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(2,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(2,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(2,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(2,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(2,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(3,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(3,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(3,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(3,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(3,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(3,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(3,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td>5</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(4,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(4,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(4,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(4,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(4,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(4,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(4,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(5,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(5,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(5,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(5,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(5,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(5,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(5,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td>7</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(6,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(6,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(6,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(6,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(6,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(6,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(6,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(7,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(7,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(7,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(7,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(7,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(7,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(7,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td>9</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(8,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(8,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(8,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(8,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(8,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(8,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(8,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(9,2,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(9,3,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(9,4,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(9,5,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(9,6,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(9,7,0)~</td>
            <td>~ErrorHistory(9,8,0)~</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <h2 class="middle white_font expander" onclick="expander('cycle')" id="cycle_title"></h2>
      <div class="hidden" id="cycle" style="overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
        <table cellspacing="0" class="data_tab" id="cycle_history" style="layout:fixed">
          <tr>
            <th>Nr</th>
            <th>Ah</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tbody id="extended_cycles">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <h2 class="middle white_font expander" onclick="expander('error_tab')" id="error_tab_title">EEPROM data</h2>
      <div class="hidden" id="error_tab" style="overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
        <table cellspacing="0" class="data_tab" id="eeprom_data">
          <tr>
            <td>00: ~EEPROM(0)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>10: ~EEPROM(1)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20: ~EEPROM(2)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>30: ~EEPROM(3)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>40: ~EEPROM(4)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>50: ~EEPROM(5)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>60: ~EEPROM(6)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>70: ~EEPROM(7)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>80: ~EEPROM(8)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>90: ~EEPROM(9)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>A0: ~EEPROM(10)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>B0: ~EEPROM(11)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>C0: ~EEPROM(12)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>D0: ~EEPROM(13)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>E0: ~EEPROM(14)~</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>F0: ~EEPROM(15)~</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
    <script>
      set_language_for_raw_data_();
      Raw_Data_Requests();
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

set_language_for_raw_data_():

```
document.getElementById("menu_title").innerHTML = d12;
document.getElementById("raw_data_title").innerHTML = t5;
document.getElementById("version_title").innerHTML = t7;
document.getElementById("cumulatives_title").innerHTML = t8;
document.getElementById("error_title").innerHTML = t9;
document.getElementById("cycle_title").innerHTML = t11;
```

checkLanguage():

```
language = getCookie("language");
if (language == "")
    applySystemLanguage();

setTranslations(language);
```

setTranslations(language):

```
switch (language){
    default:
    case "en":
        d12="Show RAW data";
        t5="Real time measurements";
        t7="Version";
        t8="Cumulatives";
        t9="Error history";
        t11="Cycle history";
    break;
}
```

Comment: You can work with rxjs, or another framework that has promises. But it easier if you also show the code of both functions

Comment: does this `set_language_for_raw_data_` function have a return values? and what type?

Comment: is there an async call inside set_language_for_raw_data_();? I am assuming that it does because you mentioned that it does not happen until Raw_Data_Requests() is finished. you can put a breakpoint inside set_language_for_raw_data_();

Comment: Please include the code for your two functions (**set_language_for_raw_data_** and **Raw_Data_Requests**) for us to be able help you.

Comment: @Roljhon No it does not.

Comment: @Laura you can create a global variable which you can set it to true at the end of your code inside `set_language_for_raw_data_` function. After that set a condition if the global var returns true then fire your `Raw_Data_Requests`

Comment: @Roljhon When I do that, nothing changes. The thing is, when I set a breakpoint on Raw_Data_Requests() the translations are shown and it reaches that breakpoint in not even a second, but when I remove that breakpoint, the translations are only shown after about 10 seconds...

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, it can't do simultaneous tasks at the same time. So I think you need to read more about promises here is a good site to start with (https://davidwalsh.name/promises)

Answer (score 0):

With rxjs you can do someting like

```
set_language_for_raw_data_(){
    //Your code
    return Observable.of(language );
}

set_language_for_raw_data_().subscribe(() => Raw_Data_Requests());
```

Here, you wait until the set_language_for_raw_data_ returns an observable. You can then subscribe on it. From the moment the observable is completed, it will call the next function.

The complete explanation you can find on http://reactivex.io/, But take some time and check how Observables are working

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make the translations show was add a timeout:

```
set_language_for_raw_data_();
setTimeout(function(){
    Raw_Data_Requests();
}, 20);
```

Apparently this was enough time for the html to be shown/updated.